# $n$ is properly represented by $x^2+xy+y^2$ if and only if $n$ is not divisible by 9 or any prime $3k+2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to show a positive integer $n$ is properly represented by the binary quadratic form $x^2+xy+y^2$ if and only if $n$ is not divisible by 9 or any prime of the form $3k+2$? It boils down to showing $-3$ is a square mod $4n$ if and only if $n=3^a\cdot\prod p^b$ where $a=0$ or $1$ and $p$ are primes of the form $3k+1$ but I'm stuck.

I'm currently going through Niven's *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* Chapters 3.6-3.7.

Comment: One way is to use arithmetic in the ring of Eisenstein integers.

Comment: we have $x^2+xy+y^2=(3a^2+b^2)/4=(b+a\sqrt{3}i)(b-\sqrt{3}i)/4$ with $a=x+y$, $b=x-y$. Maybe you can mimic the proof of numbers represented of the form $a^2+b^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct approach in the style of Gauss' proof of Fermat's theorem on sums of 2  squares. Let $\omega$ be a primitive 3-rd root of 1. Introduce the imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbf Q(\omega)=\mathbf Q (\sqrt {-3})$ and its ring of integers $A=\mathbf Z[\omega]$ (the so called Eisenstein ring, known to be a PID; beware, $A\neq \mathbf Z[\sqrt {-3}]$). The norm map $N:K^*\to {\mathbf Q}^*$ defined by the formula $N(x-y\omega)=(x-y\omega)(x-y{\omega}^2)=x^2+xy+y^2$ is a multiplicative function. So, restricting $N$ to $A-(0)$ and using the prime factorization of the integer $n$, you can bring back your problem to the determination of the powers $p^a$ of rational primes which are norms from $A-(0)$.

The classical theorem on ramification/decomposition of rational primes $p$ in a quadratic field easily yields the following : 1) If $p \equiv 2$ mod $3$, then $p$  is inert, i.e. remains prime in $A$ ; 2) If $p\equiv 1$ mod $3$, then $p$ splits in $A$, i.e. $p=\pi.\bar\pi$, where $\pi$ and $\bar\pi$ are two non-associate conjugate primes of $A$ ; 3) If $p=3$, then $1-\omega$ is prime in $A$ and $3=-{\omega}^2(1-\omega)^2$. Let us show for example the case 2): suppose that $p\equiv $ mod $3$ ; then $(\frac {-3}p)=1$ and the classical theorem for $\mathbf Q (\sqrt {-3})$ states that $p$ splits.

*Conclusion*: the only powers $p^a$ which are norms from $A-(0)$ are powers of $p\equiv 1$ mod $3$ and powers of $9$.

Answer (score 0):

$4n=(x+2y)^2+3x^2$

For odd $p,$

$$p|n\implies ((x+2y)/x)^2\equiv-3\pmod p$$

Use   [For what odd prime p is -3 a quadratic residues? Non-residue?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701023/for-what-odd-prime-p-is-3-a-quadratic-residues-non-residue)

Comment: You mean $(x-y)^2+3(x+y)^2$

Comment: @Julian, I meant the current version. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: How do we know that $(x+2y)/x$ is necessarily an integer?

Comment: @user500144, First of all, if prime $p>3$ divides $x,p$ must divide $x+2y\implies p $ divides $y$  For $(x,p)=1,$ we can always find $z$ such that $zx\equiv 1\implies x^{-1}\equiv z\pmod p$